# How to configure webpack css loader in a vue-cli project

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, node-modules, vue-cli

I have a newly generated [vue-cli](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CLI) project. I've installed the Pure.CSS framework using `npm install purecss --save`. But I cannot figure out how to integrate, import or load the css framework into my project. I don't even know where in the project I should keep my usual css (mystyle.css etc.) files. I am guessing it should be inside the `src/assets` directory. Here is the `vue-cli` [Project Structure](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/structure.html).

How can I bundle all the css files in a single file, such as app.css or main.css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import it as any other resource by:

```
import '../node_modules/purecss/path/to/css/file.css'
```

in your `App.vue` for instance.

Ensure the path to node_modules is correct.

Then you're ready to use `purecss` styles anywhere in your templates.

Comment: Proper statement is  import '../node_modules/purecss/build/pure-min.css'